# Discord.py как выдавать роль по реакции

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import datetime
from datetime import date

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print('------')
    

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.event
async def weekstart(ctx):
    global vc
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    user = ctx.author
    channels = ctx.message.channel
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": запущен',
                    description='Для того чтобы приянть учатие в нем используйте реакцию ниже',
                    colour=discord.Color.purple())
    ad = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": запущен',
                    description='Через 12 часов будет завершен сбор игроков',
                    colour=discord.Color.green())
    adnoend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": сбор игроков завершен',
                    description='Сбор игроков завершён,игровой канал создан,для завершения эвента воспользуйтесь командой >weekstop',
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) 
    mes = await user.send(embed=ad) 
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await asyncio.sleep(10) # 24 часов это 86400 секунд
    await message.clear_reaction('✅')
    vc = await guild.create_voice_channel("Event weekends", category= None, reason=None)
    await vc.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, connect = False)#там где *role айди роли ставите 
    await vc.set_permissions(ctx.guild.get_role(810872023436886026), connect = True)
    inv = await vc.create_invite(reason=None)
    noend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": сбор игроков завершен',
                    description=f"Сбор игроков завершён,игровой канал создан {inv} ",
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    ev = await ctx.send(embed=noend) 
    ev1 = await user.send(embed=adnoend)

    
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.event
async def weekstop(ctx): 
    global vc
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    today = date.today()
    user = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await ctx.message.delete()
    end = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": завершён',
                    description='Всем спасибо за участие!Канал будет полностью очищен через 5 секунд!',
                    colour=discord.Color.red())
    en = await ctx.send(embed=end)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await channel.purge(limit=100)
    await vc.delete()
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    dataevent = discord.Embed(title=f'Последний эвент был:',
                    description= f"{today}",
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    ev = await ctx.send(embed=dataevent)
    adend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": завершён',
                    description='Эвент был успешно завершен!',
                    colour=discord.Color.red())
    anss = await user.send(embed=adend)
    
    
bot.run('token)
```

Как выдать поль пользователю при добавлении реакции по сообщением
сообщение отправляется командой `>weekstart` и автоматически добавляет реакцию под сообщение

Comment: На просторах интернета есть куча гайдов как по нажатию на реакцию получить роль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На просторах интернета вы можете найти разные реализации.Вот **[ЗДЕСЬ](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/reaction_roles.py)** наглядно можно посмотреть на примеры действий с ролями без "лишнего".